# Logging application wide mouse clicks in Delphi

Tags: delphi, logging, mouse

I am trying to track and log what a user does in my app.  One way to help is to have a list of what buttons and menu etc they click as they use the program.  Then if the program crashes for any reason I have a log of the exact steps they took to try and reproduce the issue.

So I drop an ApplicationEvents component on the main form and then under OnMessage I use...

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;var Handled: Boolean);
var Target: TControl;
    Point: TPoint;
begin
     Handled := FALSE;
     if (Msg.Message = WM_LBUTTONDOWN) then
     begin
          GetCursorPos(Point);
          Target := FindDragTarget(Point,True);
          if Assigned(Target) then
          begin
               AddLogText('CLICKED '+(Target).owner.name+'.'+(Target).name);
          end;
    end;
end;
```

This does seem to work and I can log all clicks but there is a nasty side effect.  Sometimes and without a reporducable set of steps the above code seems to eat a mouse click.  This means at seemingly random times a toolbar button won't click and need a double-click.  Or a dialog button needs a double-click.  Needless to say this is annoying as hell and made me question my mouse before I realised it was only happening in my app.

If I remark the above code the issue is gone.

So does anyone have a reliable way to log all clicks across all forms/objects in my Delphi program without causing bad side effects?  I want to intercept and log all clicks but not have any of the messages mysteriously eaten.

Edit: after the helpful comments below, this is the current working code.

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;var Handled: Boolean);
var Target: TControl;
    Point: TPoint;
begin
     Handled := FALSE;
     if (Msg.Message = WM_LBUTTONDOWN) then
     begin
          Point.X := Msg.pt.X;
          Point.Y := Msg.pt.Y;
          Target := FindDragTarget(Point,True);
          if Assigned(Target) and Assigned(Target.Owner) then
          begin
               //use (Target).owner.name and (Target).name for logging here
          end;
     end;
end;
```

Comment: Seems implausible. What happens when you remove various code in the function above. Start by removing the call to AddLogText

Comment: Thank you so much for that simple idea I overlooked.  Remarking that line fixed the problem, so not a Delphi issue.  I will see what could be causing that in my log code, but for now this is a non-issue.

Comment: This is really debugging 101. Use techniques like this to identify and narrow down the source of your issue, then it is likely that the problem will become obvious.

Comment: You can use Windows [Problem Steps Recorder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/22878/windows-10-record-steps).

Comment: On a side note, `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` is a posted message, so there is a slight delay in receiving it. The mouse may have moved between the time the event is generated and the time you receive it. As such, you shouldn't be using `GetCursorPos()`, use the coordinates inside the message instead.

Comment: Just to clarify, this means using Point.X := Msg.pt.X; Point.Y := Msg.pt.Y; rather than GetCursorPos .

Comment: No, [GetMessagePos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644938(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: What syntax do I use to call GetMessagePos from within Delphi?  The Msg.pt.X code above works fine.

Comment: I'm a little confused @Victoria. Docs say that `GetMessagePos` *retrieves the cursor position for the last message retrieved by the GetMessage function*. Who calls `GetMessage`?

Comment: @saastn the message loop does that

Comment: @Victoria in this case, knowing the actual message, it makes sense to use the point supplied in the message params

Comment: If commenting out `AddLogText` resolved the issue, that doesn't guarantee the problem is in that function. Commenting out the line also removed `(Target).owner.name` and `(Target).name`. The first of those violates _Law of Demeter_ and raises an important alarm bell: _Is `(Target).owner` always assigned? I doubt it; in which case you'll sometimes get access violations._ (You checked `Target`, but not `Target.Owner`.)

Comment: Doesn't the "if Assigned(Target) then" handle if it assigned or not?  Or should I be checking for if not equal to nil?

Comment: No, `Asigned(Target)` only checks ***Target***. It doesn't check Target ***.Owner***. You need an additional `Assigned(Target.Owner)` check. On a side note: _Do you handle non-mouse action? Your approach is not particularly robust for keyboard users._

Comment: OK, I now changed the check to "if Assigned(Target) and Assigned(Target.Owner) then".  I never got access violations before with that check, but it is good to be sure.  I am only tracking mouse clicks at this stage.  The program is very mouse orientated.

Comment: Your use of the program is very mouse oriented, but you might be surprised about how other users approach it

Comment: @David, sure, I missed the fact it's the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message :( My fault, sorry for misleading advice.

Comment: @David.  How would I add code to intercept key entry then?  Could I have the same parent object tracking so I could then have eg "Typed x at form1.edit3.text"?